# Auto update cart on click for payment plan (WooCommerce All Products For Subscriptions)

Tags: woocommerce, cart, woocommerce-subscriptions

I'm stuck on one last hurdle before I can launch my Woocommerce store and I'll be forever grateful  if you could help me.

All the info I find on automatically updating the Woocommerce cart is for changes in quantity. In my case, I would like the cart to be automatically updated with the payment plan the person chooses. They can either pay in full or in a monthly subscription. I use the Woocommerce Subscriptions and WooCommerce All Products For Subscriptions add-ons.

[image: See what the cart looks like.]

What could I add in functions.php to have the payment plan and the amount updated depending on the option the client chooses?

I am not a developer but can find my way around code. I tried to change the code shared in other threads about auto updating quantities but couldn't do it correctly.